# Flutter - Error: The getter X isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class `TripController` that contains a private field `_updatedAccount`. I created a getter in order to get from outside.

```
class TripController {
  final String _accountId;
  final BuildContext _context;
  Account _updatedAccount;  
  Account updatedAccount() => _updatedAccount;


  TripController(this._accountId, this._context);
...
}
```

In another class, where I perfectly have access to the `TripController` class, I have the code :

```
onTap: () {
 TripController _tripController =
 new TripController(_account.id, context);
 _tripController.add(context);
 _account.trips  = _tripController.updatedAccount.trips;
 _account.notifyListeners();
},
```

And here, `updatedAccount` from `_tripController.updatedAccount.trips` is underlined in red with the message : `The getter 'updatedAccount' isn't defined for the class 'TripController'`

Did I misdeclared the getter ?

Comment: `dart pub cache repair` worked for me on iOS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I finally fixed it. I don't know why, but I had to delete the code related to TripController, and ther re-write it again. I don't know why, maybe it was an Editor problem, I'm using VScode.

Comment: For me it worked by reloading VS code window. 

To reload window:
`(Cmd/ Ctrl )+Shift+P` and search for reload there should be an option called ```Developer: Reload Window```

Caution: Reloading window will kill the current running terminals / emulators / sessions

Answer (score 3):

You have declared `updatAccount()` as a method, not as a getter. Use `_tripController.updatedAccount().trips;` or change the method to a getter `Account get updatedAccount => _updatedAccount;`

Comment: With parenthesis, the error message changes and becomes `The method 'updatedAccount' isn't defined for the class 'TripController'.`

Comment: Do you have another class called 'TripController'?

Comment: No, I don't. What I don't understand is that I have access to all the other methods, but not this one. It doesn't recognize it. EDIT : actually, when I try to add another test() method, it doesn't work neither

Comment: As if it didn't want to take into account the changes I do to my `TripController` class.

Comment: That's weird. Have you tired to clean/rebuild your project?

Comment: Yes, i did try `flutter clean`

Comment: Too bad, I have no further idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this error and the problem was my IDE, not my code.
This solution worked for me in **Android Studio** :

File -> Invalidate Catches... -> Invalidate And Restart

Answer (score 0):

You are using the classic method syntax declaration, in Dart language, prefer using this kind of syntax for getters:

```
Account get updatedAccount => _updatedAccount;
```

And call it the way you did.
Else you should call it like a classic method:

```
_tripController.updatedAccount().trips
```

Please follow this link for further information:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters

Comment: I tried to add the get, but the message is the same :/

Comment: Did you remove parenthesis aswell ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the model class name you use might the same with existing name of Widget or Plugin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32322487)

Answer (score 0):

Check your imported libraries on the top of your file where the problem is. In my case, Android Studio auto-imported an object from the core Flutter library with the same name as the model I've defined on my own.

I just deleted the import and then imported my own object from *my_models.dart* file.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do when getting an exception in Flutter - is to restart IDE.